# Can't figure out how to use discord.py ctx

Tags: discord.py

I have tried to convert my discord bot's commands to using ctx instead of interactions but the code I have tried below does not work.

```
@bot.command(description="Says test")
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Test")
```

My issue is that the command never loads.

Updated code but still broken

```
import discord
from discord import ui
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents = discord.Intents.all())

# Run code
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('The bot has sucuessfully logged in: {0.user}'.format(bot))
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type = discord.ActivityType.listening, name = f"Chilling Music - {len(bot.guilds)}"))

# Commands
@bot.command(description="Says Hello")
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"Hello {ctx.author.mention}!")
@bot.command(description="Plays music")
async def play(ctx, song_name : str):
    await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
    await ctx.send(f"Now playing: {song_name}")
@bot.command(description="The amount of servers the bot is in")
async def servercount(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"Chill Bot is in {len(bot.guilds)} discord servers!")
@bot.command(description="The bots ping")
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"Pong\nChill Bot's ping is\n{round(bot.latency * 1000)} ms")
@bot.command(description="Announcement command")
async def announce(ctx, message : str):
    await ctx.send(message)
@bot.command(description="Support Invite")
async def support(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} Please join our server for support! [invite]", ephemeral=True)
@bot.command(description = "Syncs up commands")
async def sync(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Synced commands!", ephemeral=True)

bot.run('')
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question, and you didn't show what you tried. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: Okay adding what I tried sorry.

Comment: It's because you have self as a parameter? Unless you re-wrote it object oriented..?

Comment: Trying it without self right now.

Comment: Still doesn't work but I added the test piece to the code so it is viewable directly in the code.

Comment: I don't want to half to use the ctx = await bot.get_context(interaction) every time I want to use ctx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your commands don't work because you incorrectly created an `on_message` event handler.

By overwriting it and not calling `Bot.process_commands()`, the library no longer tries to parse incoming messages into commands.

The docs also show this in the Frequently Asked Questions (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working)

> Overriding the default provided on_message forbids any extra commands from running. To fix this, add a bot.process_commands(message) line at the end of your on_message.

Also, don't auto-sync (you're doing it in `on_ready`). Make a message command and call it manually whenever you want to sync.

Comment: Wait should I use the @bot.command or should I keep the @tree.command?

Comment: discord.app_commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Application command 'hello' not found

Comment: Depends on what you want to do, it's your bot not mine. If you don't want any more slash commands then remove every `@tree.command()` function. If you want both then you can keep them.

Comment: You're getting that error because you removed the slash commands in your code, but haven't synced yet, so as far as Discord is aware they still exist. Sync manually & wait for the changes to go through and then you won't have that anymore.

Comment: I put the changes I made up top.

Comment: How do you sync manually??

Comment: By making a message command that only you can run, and calling `tree.sync()` in that. You can then invoke  that command in Discord. By auto-syncing in `on_ready` you spammed the API endpoint & Discord ratelimited you from using it for a while. The limits for global syncing are quite harsh.

Comment: And yeah the changes you made confirm what I said in my comment. You removed it, but didn't tell Discord about it, so they think it still exists.

Comment: It seems like I can't use ctx if I want to use slash commands because it throws this. discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'hello' raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Interaction' object has no attribute 'send'

Comment: Yes, slash commands use `Interactions` instead of `Context`. You can't mix your code. A message command uses `Context`, a slash command doesn't. You can't call `Context`'s methods on an `Interaction`... Use `ctx` in your message command, and use `interaction` in your slash command...

Comment: Also, add a check to that `sync` command. You don't want to let other people invoke that.

Comment: I changed it to use context now so I will not be needing the sync command thanks though. I have it figured out now.

Comment: What am I supposed to do when my issue is solved?

Comment: Accept my answer, like I said. Click the green checkmark.

Comment: Okay. One last thing can you use / commands and ! commands like bots like Dyno?

Comment: You mean both at the same time? Yes, just have _both_ message _and_ slash commands in your code & sync the slash commands.

Comment: Also one more thing sorry, How would I go about making it so only I could use the sync command?

Comment: Also how would I go about using slash commands and the ! commands at the same time? I can only have on command_prefix at once right?